# create html document given a document name from html text input

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to create a html document with a name  given from a html text input. i dont know how i can write that file to a location though; i want to write the file to a specific directory. this is what I have figured out so far:

```
var title = document.getElementById("docTitle").value

function append(){
    console.log("creating new document")
    createHTMLDocument(title)
    FileSystem.writeFile(title, htmlContent, (error) => {/*handle error*/});
}
```

the input value from the html text input is assigned to a variable which is put into the `writeFile`, and function `append()` is activated by a html button. ".html" will be put into the text input as the name so no extra code is needed to create the document specifically as html.

please help

Comment: JavaScript can't write to files directly. You have to use a file selector for the user to specify the location.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is a sandbox from which most of the user's operating system or filesystem isn't available to a website, this due to security concerns.

This means you will have to offer the file you create as if it is a download;

```
const button = document.getElementById('download');

function download(filename, text) {
  const element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => download('test', '<h1>Hello world</h1>'));
```